# Induced current in a circular loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, magnetostatics

In this question I tried using right hand thumb rule for long wire to get magnetic field into plane of paper which induces clockwise current in Loop,again by thumb rule. The problem arises when force is asked for which you cannot use thumb rule and for using right hand Flemings rule you need a certain direction of content not current looping.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this way: clockwise current in the loop creates flux into paper.
It would want to oppose the trend, which fixes the trend - flux change due to motion has to be out of paper, towards us.
That is achieved when motion is in eastern direction.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: That is achieved when motion is in eastern direction. Please explain (which rule and how you use it)

Comment: So, we want to move the loop, so that flux change is toward us.

Comment: If you fix position, the flux from infinite wire is into paper.

Comment: If you decrease the magnitude, you will get desired action - flux change toward us. decreasing flux magnitude is achieved by moving loop farther from wire. Hope this helps.